# Form target attribute strict compliance and quirks mode

Tags: javascript, html

I have a couple of pages in my app in which I generate pdf reports that may take quite a long time to load. So I have the report options form, pop out the report in a new window. So other than not complying with HTML 4.01 standards, are there any downsides (like putting browsers in quirks mode) to having a target attribute on a form.

A second part to the question is how would one go about submitting a form to a new window without a target attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So other than not complying with HTML 4.01 standards, are there any downsides (like putting browsers in quirks mode) to having a target attribute on a form.

It won't trigger quirks mode, only the Doctype influences that (and you can switch to a Transitional doctype without leaving standards mode, just use the full HTML 4.01 Transitional one *with* the URI).

The major disadvantage is that it triggers a new window, and page triggered new windows are horrible. If the delay is the problem, then I'd look at a "You'll get an email when it is ready" approach.

Comment: So it looks like setting the Doctype to strict does not trigger quirks mode with attributes that are deprecated.

Comment: As I said, only the Doctype matters for Standards/Quirks mode. Not the rest of the document.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed some weird stuff with Safari. After changing the target attribute of a form and submitting the form to a new window, all the links in the first document that use href="javascript:... are now dead as doorknobs. They don't go, they don't do, and they don't fire any click or focus events. Doorknobs.

You might be wondering why I'm using href="javascript: type links. I'm actually using ASP.Net LinkButtons, and that is how they are rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You could [use jQuery to submit the form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) and wait for a reply asynchronously. Once you get the response you could open a popup window.